# Tweaking relevance score of only certain queries

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have a use case where when the user search for certain search terms depending on the term i need to rank up or lower certain documents from the total result of that search term.

What I have tried so far:

I have added a nested field `tuning` to documents on the index that will have these custom boosting.

```
{
    _id: 1234,
    'name': 'Fancy potato masher',
    'tuning': [
        {'term': 'potato', 'rank': 5},
        {'term': 'masher', 'rank': 10}, 
    ]
},
{
    _id: 2345,
    'name': 'Decent potato masher',
    'tuning': [
        {'term': 'potato', 'rank': 3},
        {'term': 'masher', 'rank': 7},
    ]
},
{
    _id: 3456,
    'name': 'Useless potato masher',
    'tuning': [
        {'term': 'potato', 'rank': -5},
        {'term': 'masher', 'rank': -7},
    ]
},
{
    _id: 4567,
    'name': 'Ordinary potato masher',
    'tuning': []
}
```

So here when we search for `potato` or `masher`, I want the results to be in the order of `1234, 2345, 4567, 3456`.

My `sort` part of the query looks like this:

```
{
    'sort': {
        'tuning.rank' => {
            'order' => 'desc',
            'nested' => {
                'path' => 'tuning',
                'filter' => {
                    'match' => {
                        'tuning.term' => 'potato'
                    }
                }

            }
        },
    }
}
```

My results are in the order `1234, 2345, 3456, 4567`. So basically anything with missing `tuning` data is appearing at the end rather than the ones with negative rank.

How is this problem solved normally without getting into fancy learning to rank etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `missing` parameter as shown in the below example.

Also note that the way you do i.e. making use of `nested_filter` and `nested_path` has been deprecated as mentioned in this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/search-request-sort.html#nested-sorting) post ***ES 6.2*** version.

I've mentioned how do get what you want using both latest and deprecated DSL. Feel free to use depending on which version you are using.

### Query for pre ES 6.2 version

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}      //query logic as per your requirement
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "tuning.rank": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_path": "tuning",
        "nested_filter": {
            "match": {
              "tuning.term": "potato"
            }
        },
        "missing": "0"                    <------ Note this.
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above query, just focus on the sort logic, I've just added `missing` parameter with value `0` which means that in case if the field `tuning.term` is missing, let the sort value be `0` so that documents would be sorted accordingly.

### Query for ES 6.2+ version

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort":[
    {
      "tuning.rank":{
        "order": "desc",
        "nested":{
          "path": "tuning",
          "filter":{
            "match":{
              "tuning.term": "potato"
            }
          }
        },
        "missing": "0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is how the response appears in my machine:

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1234",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Fancy potato masher",
          "tuning" : [
            {
              "term" : "potato",
              "rank" : 5
            },
            {
              "term" : "masher",
              "rank" : 10
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          5
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2345",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Decent potato masher",
          "tuning" : [
            {
              "term" : "potato",
              "rank" : 3
            },
            {
              "term" : "masher",
              "rank" : 7
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          3
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4567",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Ordinary potato masher",
          "tuning" : [ ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3456",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Fancy potato masher",
          "tuning" : [
            {
              "term" : "potato",
              "rank" : -5
            },
            {
              "term" : "masher",
              "rank" : -7
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          -5
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now if you run the query, your results would be sorted accordingly.

### Updated Answer for relevancy:

You see above that I'm using a custom sort, and for that matter, relevancy would not show up.

By default if you do not use any sorting logic, the results are sorted by relevancy and you would be able to view the `_score` value.

Also note that I'm using a match_all which would give a score of 1 to each and every document. So if you remove the sorting logic, you would be returned all documents with equal score of 1 in the query I've shared.

Relevancy is a complex topic and it depends a lot on your use case. I'd suggest you to spend sometime in looking into [function_score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) query so that you would understand how you can *influence* the score. Play around with it a bit and you would slowly start understanding how it works.

As for your comment, if you want to also show or display the `_score`, you would simply need to add _score field in your sort logic as well. So first, it would sort the documents by `tuning.rank` then it would sort based on `_score`.

Below is how its done.

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort":[
    {
      "tuning.rank":{
        "order": "desc",
        "nested":{
          "path": "tuning",
          "filter":{
            "match":{
              "tuning.term": "potato"
            }
          }
        },
        "missing": "0"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": { "order": "desc" }
    }
  ]
}
```

### Response:

```
{
  "took" : 2,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 4,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1234",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Fancy potato masher",
          "tuning" : [
            {
              "term" : "potato",
              "rank" : 5
            },
            {
              "term" : "masher",
              "rank" : 10
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          5,
          1.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2345",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Decent potato masher",
          "tuning" : [
            {
              "term" : "potato",
              "rank" : 3
            },
            {
              "term" : "masher",
              "rank" : 7
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          3,
          1.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4567",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Ordinary potato masher",
          "tuning" : [ ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          0,
          1.0
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "someindex",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "3456",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "name" : "Fancy potato masher",
          "tuning" : [
            {
              "term" : "potato",
              "rank" : -5
            },
            {
              "term" : "masher",
              "rank" : -7
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          -5,
          1.0
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Also, just so you can see how relevancy documents are not sorted by relevancy but based on your sort logic, try running the below query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "name": "potato decent"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort":[
    {
      "tuning.rank":{
        "order": "desc",
        "nested":{
          "path": "tuning",
          "filter":{
            "match":{
              "tuning.term": "potato"
            }
          }
        },
        "missing": "0"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": { "order": "desc" }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see in your results, that the document with higher _score value would still appear in lower because we are primarily sorting based on `tuning.rank`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks @Kamal, it works better now. Is there a way we can get the `_score` populating too ? Its currently NULL. Does this affect relevancy of records without tuning in any way ?

Comment: @Deepak I've updated my answer. Please review and let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: awesome! that makse sense. If i include `_score` in the sorting logic its giving me an error `No enum constant org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortOrder._SCORE` is that something you can help me with or I can start a new question to solve that. Also do you think I should be using `function_score` instead of adding logic into `sort` ?

Comment: @Deepak, I would suggest you to start a new question. That would be useful for others too who would have similar question. Do mention your use case in its entirety. For the error, note carefully how I've added `_score` above. `"_score": { "order": "desc" }`

Comment: Thanks I will close this question now. :)